How to create APEX triggers in salesforce using jsforce library
I am trying to create an Apex trigger on the Account object using jsforce. I've successfully established an OAuth connection, and I can query and create records without any issues. I've also tested creating Apex classes using jsforce and that works fine as well.
However, when I try to create an Apex trigger using the same approach, it fails without providing a clear error message.
Here's the code I'm using to create the Apex trigger:
async function createApexTrigger() {
  const conn = new jsforce.Connection({
    oauth2: {
      clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
      redirectUri: process.env.REDIRECT_URI
    },
    accessToken: process.env.ACCESS_TOKEN,
    instanceUrl: process.env.INSTANCE_URL
  });

  const triggerName = 'AccountTrigger';
  const sObjectType = 'Account';
  const triggerBody = `
    trigger AccountTrigger on Account (before insert, before update) {
      for (Account acc : Trigger.new) {
        acc.Description = 'Triggered by AccountTrigger';
      }
    }
  `;

  try {
    const apexTrigger = await conn.tooling.sobject('ApexTrigger').create({
      Name: triggerName,
      TableEnumOrId: sObjectType,
      Body: triggerBody
    });

    console.log('Apex Trigger created:', apexTrigger);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error creating Apex Trigger:', error);
  }
}

Error
INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS_ON_CROSS_REFERENCE_ENTITY
Related issue that I have found: Force.com Tooling API issues
Steps I've taken:

Successfully created Apex classes and queried objects using jsforce.
OAuth connection is working, and querying records also works fine.
Trigger creation fails when attempting to create the trigger.

What I've Tried:

Confirmed that the Apex class creation works fine with the same approach.
Checked permissions

Is there something I am missing when creating an Apex trigger through jsforce? Any help would be appreciated!

Can you check what error you are getting in response?

Just make sure that you dont have existing trigger with same name.

Have you successfully created any (on any other object, even the most simple) triggers (e.g. with an empty body) this way?

@ManjotSinghI added the error details as I recall. I ran it again this morning, and now the triggers are being created without any issues. Another developer also tried to fix it and made some settings changes, but everything had failed at that time. Now it seems to be working fine, though. Not sure what's happening—could it be related to transaction limits?

@FelixvanHove creation of classes custom objects are working just fine.
